# Two degree equation of mutually perpendicular 3D planes

Tags: geometry, 3d

> If the equation $px^2+y^2+qz^2+2yz+zx+3xy=0$ represents a pair of perpendicular planes, then find the value of $~p-q~$.

My approach is as follow:

Let the two plane equation be $ax+by+cz=0$ &$a'x+b'y+c'z=0$

As they are mutually perpendicular then $aa'+bb'+cc'=0$

On multiplying both plane we get $aa'x^2+bb'y^2+cc'z^2+(ab'+a'b)xy+(bc'+b'c)yz+(ac'+a'c)xz=0$

On comparing we get $~p+q=-1~$ after this step, I am not able to approach further.

Comment: After orthogonality condition, for $ z=0, \,px^2+y^2+3xy=0$ should be factorable. For $ y=0, \, px^2+qz^2+zx=0$  and so also for $x.$ In each case the discriminant of quadratic equation should be a perfect square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Homogeneous equation of second degree in $~x,~y~$ and $~z~$, $$px^2+y^2+qz^2+2yz+zx+3xy=0$$ represents a pair of perpendicular plains if 
$$\begin{vmatrix}
p & \dfrac 32 & \dfrac 12 \\
\dfrac 32 & 1 & 1 \\
\dfrac 12 & 1 & q
\end{vmatrix}=0\qquad\text{and}\qquad p+1+q=0$$
$$\implies 4pq-4p-9q+5=0\qquad\text{and}\qquad p=-1-q$$
$$\implies 4q(-1-q)-4(-1-q)-9q+5=0$$
$$\implies q=-3,~~~~\dfrac 34$$
and hence $~p=2,~~-\dfrac 74~.$

Therefore $~p-q~=5,~~-\dfrac 52~.$

${}$

---

---

> **Note:** A homogeneous equation of second degree in $~x,~y~$ and $~z~$, $$ax^2+by^2+cz^2+2fyz+2gzx+2hyx=0$$ represents a pair of perpendicular plains if 
>   $$\begin{vmatrix} 
> a & h & g \\ h & b & f \\ g & f & c 
> \end{vmatrix}=0\qquad\text{and}\qquad a+b+c=0$$

Comment: How did u get the determinant form just elaborate it

Comment: You can find it in any Solid Geometry Book. For example "Analytical Solid Geometry" by   Shanti Narayan, P.K. Mittal (Theorem 2.8)

Comment: Very slick, but I still wonder if there’s a way to compute $p-q$ without explicitly solving for $p$ and $q$.

Comment: @SamarImamZaidi The first condition says that the quadric is degenerate, the second comes from $\operatorname{tr}(\mathbf p\mathbf q^T+\mathbf q\mathbf p^T)=2\mathbf p^T\mathbf q$.

Comment: I don't think that it is possible @amd. The only way to do so is to use the rule $~(p-q)^2=(p+q)^2-4pq~$. The value of $~p+q~$ is $~-1~$, but the problem is in the value of $~pq~$. Here $~pq=\dfrac 14 \left(4p+9q-5\right)~$ and if you put any one of the value of $~p~$ or $~q~$ we get $~pq~$ is not a constant. So ultimately the only way (according to me) is to find the value of $~p~$ and $~q~$.